# Код команды !clear для discord бота на Python

Tags: python, discord

Мне нужен код команды !clear (чтобы очистить сообщения) для discord бота на Python. Помогите пожалуйста, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount=20): #число 20 - это число удалённых сообщений, если число не указано
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
```

Comment: Если получилось, попрошу отметить галочкой

Answer (score 0):

... документация но ладно на, держи

```py
@bot.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount: int = 10):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount)
    await ctx.send(f"Очищено **{amount}** сообщений")
```

прошу если понадобилось то галочку